# Asynchronous media download via telethon?

Tags: python, asynchronous, download, telethon

I have a channel that contains 3000 files, each of which is 1GB in size. If you download them in the usual way, it will take a very long time. Do you have any ideas?

I tried to use threads, but telethon forbids creating new threads.

Answer (score 0):

Telethon doesn't forbid the use of threads. You can mix `threading` and `asyncio` just fine, but this is often unnecessary and overly complicated.

You can instead use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

Make sure [`cryptg`](https://pypi.org/project/cryptg/) is installed or the decryption will be slow.

However, your biggest limiting factor will be Telegram's flood wait limits. So even if you try to go faster, you will hit a limit.

Comment: I tried to do `await asyncio.create_task(fast_download(client, message))` (I use FastTelethonhelper, but I have the same problem with the telethon download function) but the program doesn't want to continue until the file is downloaded to the end. Could you help me please?